# Convert dataframe into long format one column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have data as given in input section (dput below), need to convert to output with all values of two rows in one long column. I tried using transpose but cells were getting trimmed.

I don't want to hardcode since in future I might have data in 3 or 4 rows in a similar way.

P.S - I also tried pivot_longer but it didnt help

```
    structure(list(Header = c("Sat 12/3   \n358a-947a\n1017a-229p HRS   10.02", 
"Sat 12/10  \n559a-1106a\n1134a-227p HRS         8.00"), X = c("Sun 12/4   ", 
"Sun 12/11  "), X.1 = c("Mon 12/5   \n548a-1121a\n1149a-618p\n650p-845p HRS   13.95", 
"Mon 12/12  \n500a-1121a\n1151a-547p\n616p-830p HRS   14.53"), 
    X.2 = c("Tue 12/6   \n359a-1120a\n1150a-400p HRS   11.53", 
    "Tue 12/13  \n548a-1120a\n1148a-449p HRS   10.54"), X.3 = c("Wed 12/7   \n548a-1119a\n1149a-515p HRS   10.95", 
    "Wed 12/14  \n429a-1120a\n1150a-432p HRS   11.56"), X.4 = c("Thu 12/8   \n549a-1120a\n1149a-447p HRS   10.48", 
    "Thu 12/15  \n429a-1121a\n1152a-431p HRS   11.52"), X.5 = c("Fri 12/9   \n548a-1120a\n1148a-218p HRS         8.03", 
    "Fri 12/16  \n430a-1120a\n1150a-432p HRS   11.55")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

My try (with a little help)

```
pivot_longer(df, cols = c(1:7)) %>%    
  select(value) %>% 
  mutate(value=str_replace(value,"HRS","")) %>% 
  separate(.,value,into=c("day","entry1","entry2","entry3"),sep="\n") %>% 
  separate(.,entry1,into=c("time_in1","time_out1"),sep="-") %>% 
  separate(.,entry2,into=c("time_in2","time_out2"),sep="-") %>% 
  separate(.,time_out2,into=c("time_out2","duration1"),remove = FALSE,sep="    ",extra = "merge") %>% 
  separate(.,entry3,into=c("time_in3","time_out3"),sep="-") %>% 
  separate(.,time_out3,into=c("time_out3","duration2"),remove = FALSE,sep="    ") %>%
  mutate(duration=coalesce(duration1,duration2)) %>% 
  select(day, duration, time_in1,time_out1,time_in2,time_out2,time_in3,time_out3) %>% 
  separate(.,day,into=c("date","day"),extra="merge") %>% 
  mutate(day=mdy(paste0(day,"2021")),
         duration=str_trim(duration))
```

[image: Expected output][image: Required Output]

Comment: The data you provided already has 1 column and 14 rows

Comment: My bad, I just changed the dput.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about the desired output please? Do you wish to keep the date? Should the date be in a different column than the value? A way to get 1 column and as much rows as cells is: `pivot_longer(df, cols = c(1:7)) %>% 
  select(value)`

Comment: Actually my desired output is to have a dataframe with date as first column, followed by Time IN 1, Time Out 1, Time In2, Time Out2, Time in 3, Time Out3, .... if there are more. Followed by duration which is difference between Time ins & Time outs.

Comment: @MonJeanJean, The data that you see is basically a punch in & punch out time data. I want to convert it to a tidy data format which one row per day.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I think I have an answer, but it might be later in the day.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I've found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68472576)!

Comment: Answer of the year for me!

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Thanks, I appreciate it!  The answer has now been updated to properly calibrate the `date`s and `day`s, all in the wide format ( `...` | `time_in_1` | `time_out_1` | `time_in_2` | `time_out_2` | `...`) you requested.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Approach

The key was [`tidyr::separate_rows()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html), which not only separates the cell by `"\n"` but also splits the components into **rows** rather than columns.

Here, it is much **better to split into rows than into columns**. Suppose that most cells have 2 or 3 entries separated by `"\n"`; but there is a "rogue" cell, with an unusually large number (say 9) of entries, generated by someone who repeatedly clocked in and out throughout the day.

While splitting into columns would create arbitrarily many `time_in* | time_out*` columns, which remain empty (`NA`) in all rows except the "rogue"

```
   date  day        duration time_in1 time_out1 time_in2 time_out2 time_in3 time_out3 time_in4 time_out4 time_in5 time_out5 time_in6 time_out6 time_in7 time_out7 time_in8 time_out8 time_in9 time_out9
   <chr> <date>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>
#  ...   ...        ...      ...      ...       ...      ...       ...      ...       NA       NA        NA       NA        NA       NA        NA       NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
```

splitting into rows will maintain a tame (and stable) columnar structure

```
   date       day      duration time_in time_out
   <date>     <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
#  ...        ...      ...      ...     ...
#  ...        ...      ...      ...     ...
#  ...        ...      ...      ...     ...
```

without any "extraneous" columns (or rows).

## Solution

Given your sample data `df`

```
df <- structure(list(Header = c("Sat 12/3   \n358a-947a\n1017a-229p HRS   10.02", "Sat 12/10  \n559a-1106a\n1134a-227p HRS         8.00"),
                     X = c("Sun 12/4   ", "Sun 12/11  "),
                     X.1 = c("Mon 12/5   \n548a-1121a\n1149a-618p\n650p-845p HRS   13.95", "Mon 12/12  \n500a-1121a\n1151a-547p\n616p-830p HRS   14.53"), 
                     X.2 = c("Tue 12/6   \n359a-1120a\n1150a-400p HRS   11.53", "Tue 12/13  \n548a-1120a\n1148a-449p HRS   10.54"),
                     X.3 = c("Wed 12/7   \n548a-1119a\n1149a-515p HRS   10.95", "Wed 12/14  \n429a-1120a\n1150a-432p HRS   11.56"),
                     X.4 = c("Thu 12/8   \n549a-1120a\n1149a-447p HRS   10.48", "Thu 12/15  \n429a-1121a\n1152a-431p HRS   11.52"),
                     X.5 = c("Fri 12/9   \n548a-1120a\n1148a-218p HRS         8.03", "Fri 12/16  \n430a-1120a\n1150a-432p HRS   11.55")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

the following workflow

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)


# ...
# Code to generate 'df'.
# ...


year_observed <- 2016


results <- df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(!id, names_to = "column") %>%
  separate(value, into = c("date", "entries"), sep = "\n", fill = "right", extra = "merge", remove = TRUE) %>%
  separate(entries, into = c("times", "duration"), sep = "HRS", fill = "right", extra = "warn", remove = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(across(date:duration, trimws),
         date = as.Date(paste(str_extract(date, "\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}$"), year_observed, sep = "/"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         duration = as.numeric(duration),
         duration = if_else(is.na(duration), 0, duration),
         day = format(date, format = "%a")) %>%
  separate_rows(times, sep = "\n") %>%
  separate(times, into = c("time_in", "time_out"), sep = "-", fill = "warn", extra = "warn", remove = TRUE) %>%
  # ...Further Transformations... %>%
  select(id, date, day, duration, time_in, time_out)


# View results.
results
```

should yield `results` like

```
# A tibble: 28 x 6
      id date       day   duration time_in time_out
   <int> <date>     <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
 1     1 2016-12-03 Sat       10.0 358a    947a    
 2     1 2016-12-03 Sat       10.0 1017a   229p    
 3     1 2016-12-04 Sun        0   NA      NA      
 4     1 2016-12-05 Mon       14.0 548a    1121a   
 5     1 2016-12-05 Mon       14.0 1149a   618p    
 6     1 2016-12-05 Mon       14.0 650p    845p    
 7     1 2016-12-06 Tue       11.5 359a    1120a   
 8     1 2016-12-06 Tue       11.5 1150a   400p    
 9     1 2016-12-07 Wed       11.0 548a    1119a   
10     1 2016-12-07 Wed       11.0 1149a   515p    
# ... with 18 more rows
```

where `id` identifies (by row number) the original record in `df`.

To pivot into your [newly specified output](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121014226), simply execute this code, or append it to the existing workflow:

```
wide_results <- results %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>% mutate(entry = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(date, day, duration), names_from = entry, names_glue = "{.value}_{entry}", values_from = c(time_in, time_out)) %>%
  # Select so as to alternate between 'time_in_*' and 'time_out_*'.
  select(order(as.numeric(str_extract(colnames(.), "\\d+$")), str_extract(colnames(.), "^time_(in|out)"), na.last = FALSE))


# View results.
wide_results
```

You should obtain `wide_results` like:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 9
   date       day   duration time_in_1 time_out_1 time_in_2 time_out_2 time_in_3 time_out_3
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     
 1 2016-12-03 Sat      10.0  358a      947a       1017a     229p       NA        NA        
 2 2016-12-04 Sun       0    NA        NA         NA        NA         NA        NA        
 3 2016-12-05 Mon      14.0  548a      1121a      1149a     618p       650p      845p      
 4 2016-12-06 Tue      11.5  359a      1120a      1150a     400p       NA        NA        
 5 2016-12-07 Wed      11.0  548a      1119a      1149a     515p       NA        NA        
 6 2016-12-08 Thu      10.5  549a      1120a      1149a     447p       NA        NA        
 7 2016-12-09 Fri       8.03 548a      1120a      1148a     218p       NA        NA        
 8 2016-12-10 Sat       8    559a      1106a      1134a     227p       NA        NA        
 9 2016-12-11 Sun       0    NA        NA         NA        NA         NA        NA        
10 2016-12-12 Mon      14.5  500a      1121a      1151a     547p       616p      830p      
11 2016-12-13 Tue      10.5  548a      1120a      1148a     449p       NA        NA        
12 2016-12-14 Wed      11.6  429a      1120a      1150a     432p       NA        NA        
13 2016-12-15 Thu      11.5  429a      1121a      1152a     431p       NA        NA        
14 2016-12-16 Fri      11.6  430a      1120a      1150a     432p       NA        NA
```

## Note

You must supply the `year_observed` (here [`2016`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121014226)) to correctly contextualize the dates written in `m/d` format. Otherwise, they will calibrate to the year `2021`, which will skew the `day`s of the week.

## Warning

These dates (`12/3`, etc.) are in December, and close to the end of the calendar year.  If any of these entries "cross over" (from `2016`) into the next year (ex. `1/1/2017`), they will be incorrectly calibrated to the former year (ex. `1/1/2016`), and thus have an incorrect `date` and week`day`.

However, if your dates do cross over, that's a good indication that the full date (`12/3/2016`) should have been notated in the original cells, in which case

```
results <- df %>%
  # ... %>%
  mutate(
    # ...
    date = as.Date(str_extract(date, "(\\d{1,2}/){2,2}\\d{4,4}$"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
    # ...
  ) # ... %>%
```

would have sufficed to properly parse the `date`s.

Comment: Hi, The year was 2016 actually. More importantly, this is one of the best answer I have received to the question. Appreciate the depth & yes I get the separate rows logic for the rogue cell. I just have one question which is slightly basic. I want to conver this final dataframe back to pivot_wider with each date occupying one row.

Comment: Just to reiterate amazed by the depth of the answer.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Happy to help, and thank you for your kind words!  As for that last `pivot_wider()`, would you mind updating your question with a sample of what you want the final output to look like?

Comment: Have multiple columns of time in & Time out. Just updated the q with expected output

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Thank you!  So then, you don't want it in long format after all, but rather in wide?  There is a weakness to this, which I mention in my **Approach** section: if someone clocks in (and then out) 20 times in a day, you'll need 40 columns for your entire dataset, and those will mostly be `NA`.  But if you really do want it in wide format, I think `pivot_longer()` won't really be needed at all...

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Alternatively, if you're exporting this to Excel anyway, you can do the pivoting (wider) in Excel. It might even be easier that way, once R has properly cleansed and parsed the data into long form.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh In the meantime, I corrected the date handling, to use the correct `year_observed` (`2016`) and so properly calibrate the week`day`s.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I just updated the solution to give you wide results.  Enjoy!

Comment: I just saw the solution, thank you very much really appreciate the select order part. I really wanted to do it the same way

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I'm happy I could help!  :)